# Retrieving and caching nested objects from a REST API

Tags: c#, .net, rest, design-patterns

I have a series of nested objects, exposed over a REST API, like so:

```
class Category
{
      int id;
      string name;
      List<Subcategory> subcategories;
}

class Subcategory
{
      int id;
      string name;
      List<Product> products;
}

class Product
{
     int id;
     string name;
     List<Model> models;
}

class Model
{
    int id;
    string name;
    Dictionary<string, string> metadata;
}
```

These objects can be accessed over a REST API with the following end points

```
// get a list of categories
GET /categories 

// get a category                                   
GET /categories/:id

// Get subcategories for a product
GET /categories/:categoryId/subcategories

// Get a subcategory
GET //categories/:categoryId/:subcategoryId


//Get products under a subcategory
GET /categories/:categoryId/:subcategoryId/products

//Get a product
/categories/:categoryId/:subcategoryId/:productId

//Get models
/categories/:categoryId/:subcategoryId/:productId/models


Get a model under a product
/categories/:categoryId/:subcategoryId/:productId/:modelId
```

What design pattern do I use to design a data access layer on the client side? 
Please note that my  client only reads these objects, it doesn't write to them. 
DAO? Repository? I am a bit confused between the two, not sure what would be applicable here.

Comment: because your client is accessing these objects over a RESTful api, why not take advantage of HTTP caching?

Answer (score 0):

For applications with complex behavior, usually business applications, [the Repository is a better choice](http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2012/11/18/The-Data-Access-Layer-%28DAL%29-Explained.aspx) as most of the time a business object is different than the way it's persisted.

While a Repository is a concept, it is implemented as a DAO, at least from the application point of view. In fact every object used to deal with the storage is a DAO, but the Repository is a specialized DAO. It deals only with Business Objects and acts as a facade for other lower level DAOs (such as an ORM).

A repository centralizes the access logic for a service and provides a substitution point for unit tests. Services are often expensive to invoke and benefit from caching strategies that are implemented within the repository. ([Repository pattern on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx))

[Web Service Repositories diagram on MSDN](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC340239.png)

As for caching, you could:

1. Caching application block: for its' nice level of abstraction, configuration ease and desktop plus server side apps capabilities, even though deprecated in Enterprise Library 6.
2. ASP.NET’s rich caching framework: ([Grigori Melnik MSFT on MSDN blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2011/04/08/on-deprecation.aspx))
3. .NET Framework 4.0 System.Runtime.Caching classes.